# Python import shadowing different between 3.4.6 and 3.5.2

Tags: python, import, python-internals, shadowing

Python import shadowing seems to be different between version 3.4.6 and 3.5.2 :

```
$ cat time.py
from time import time
$ pyenv global 3.4.6
$ python -V
Python 3.4.6
$ python time.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "time.py", line 1, in <module>
    from time import time
  File "/home/vagrant/tmp/time.py", line 1, in <module>
    from time import time
ImportError: cannot import name 'time'
$ pyenv global 3.5.2 
$ python -V
Python 3.5.2
$ python time.py
$ echo no error
no error
```

Question 1: Why is... those things ?

Question 2: Is it there something in a changelog about that ? I can't find anything...

Comment: What is the output of `python -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)'` for both interpreters?

Comment: In both cases, the first path is an empty string. Impossible to paste, too much characters.

Answer (score 7):

[The documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) states that

> When a module named `spam` is imported, **the interpreter first searches
>   for a built-in module with that name**. If not found, it then searches
>   for a file named `spam.py` in a list of directories given by the
>   variable `sys.path`.

(emphasis mine)

`time` wasn't a built-in module module in Python 3.4, but that changed in Python 3.5:

```
me@temp:~$ python3.4 -c 'import sys; print("time" in sys.builtin_module_names)'
False
me@temp:~$ python3.5 -c 'import sys; print("time" in sys.builtin_module_names)'
True
```

You can see the patch that introduced the change [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/2c0a91606105e1606d886c198ea7ed1b195c692f#diff-d298ad39cf8496884678269f23f24682) (related to [issue 5309](https://bugs.python.org/issue5309)). Considering that the changelog [mentions the issue 5309](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#distutils), but doesn't say anything re. the `time` module, it's safe to say that the change was a side-effect and is an implementation detail of CPython.

Since `time` isn't a built-in module in CPython 3.4, and the first directory in [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path) is the current script directory, `from time import time` attempts to import the `time` attribute from your `time.py` file, but fails and throws the `ImportError`.

In CPython 3.5 `time` *is* a built-in module. As per the quote above, running `from time import time` successfully imports the built-in module, without searching for modules on `sys.path`.

Both CPython versions will raise the same error if you shadow a non-builtin module from the standard library, such as `inspect`:

```
me@temp:~$ cat inspect.py 
from inspect import signature
me@temp:~$ python3.4 -c 'import inspect'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/me/inspect.py", line 1, in <module>
    from inspect import signature
ImportError: cannot import name 'signature'
me@temp:~$ python3.5 -c 'import inspect'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/me/inspect.py", line 1, in <module>
    from inspect import signature
ImportError: cannot import name 'signature'
```

Comment: If the import machinery is willing to special-case names like this, why not put *every* standard library module into an exceptions list, so that [the standard library doesn't accidentally try to import the user's code instead of its own](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52271581/523612)?