# Import package with the same name as current file

Tags: python, python-import

I have the following piece of code that looks like it might be able to import a package that has the same name as the script that is being run, but it goes into infinite recursion:

```py
def import_non_local2(name, custom_name=None):
    custom_name = custom_name or name

    from importlib.util import find_spec, module_from_spec

    spec = find_spec(name, sys.path[1:])
    mod = module_from_spec(spec)

    spec.name = custom_name

    spec.loader.exec_module(mod)



whois_service = import_non_local2('whois', 'whois_service')
```

I'm trying to convert the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6032023/102315) to stop using the  deprecated `imp`.

Comment: rename your script and problem resolved.

Comment: `import some_reserved_name as some_other_name` ?

Comment: I don't want to rename the script. That's the point.

Comment: @JacobIRR That imports my current script first instead of the package so does not work.

Comment: Facing the same issue. Did you ever resolve this?