# How to handle same name python modules from local and "local" remote git repositories

Tags: python, git

When developing some of my code, I need to import modules from my local repository, but these would conflict with my remote repository which resides on a shared drive (repo to which I need to maintain access).

This brings conflict and I need to specify each time if I want to load from the local or remote repo.

Adapting from this https://stackoverflow.com/a/6032023/11993709 works, but not sure it is efficient.

**Background:**

I am developing a shared Python library to be used by my team and want to use version control with Git. In this library, some people need to have access only, and some need to work on.

I have built a bare remote repo on our shared driveand have also cloned that as a normal repo on the shared drive, so people can have access to the latest code.

- For people using the shared repo: They add the path to the folder on "PYTHONPATH" and just need to import modules as normal.
- For people editing the standard repo: They need to clone repo to their local directory and push changes to the remote repo. These people would need to be able to import both from the shared area and their own local working directory.

Potentially, I am setting this up all wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "*need to be able to import both from the shared area and their own local working directory*" Why? Why importing from local is not enough?

Comment: Because essentially the local one will be a development one. And we will need to prepare scripts using the shared repo for the people who don't quite know how to set them up.