# Error "Cannot find reference 'Document'" using python-docx

Tags: python, docx

I'm following a tutorial online on how to import a docx file using Python 3.9.2.

I've installed the following using terminal:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
pip install python-docx
```

when I run pip list it shows:

```
Package     Version
----------- -------
lxml        4.6.2
pip         21.0.1
python-docx 0.8.10
setuptools  54.0.0
wheel       0.36.2
```

However, when I enter the following code:

```
from docx import Document
document = Document()
document.save('CV.docx')
```

I get this error code:

```
"Cannot find reference 'Document' in 'docx.py'"
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is your file named `docx.py`? rename it to something else

Comment: No based on the attached tutorial, it is actually creating a new file called 'CV.docx'

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YU89CWaeO9M&list=PLwvrYc43l1MzSBvslCMVZGtLLaZTq3VTG&index=17&ab_channel=Amigoscode

Comment: Not the file you want to save. The name of your **python** file / the file in which you write code.

Comment: As mentioned by @AbdulAzizBarkat, you seem to be in this situation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031584/importing-from-builtin-library-when-module-with-same-name-exists : you have a local file docx.py that "hides" the standard module docx

Comment: The file i was using was called my_app.py

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why, but I closed my terminal, reopened it, uninstalled everything in the same order, and reinstalled it and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

**Reinstall the python-docx, Remove the docx and install python-docx**

If you already installed docx uninstall docx using the commend,

```
pip uninstall docx
```

Reinstall the Python-docx

```
pip uninstall python-docx

pip install python-docx
```