# ImportError: cannot import name 'my_function' from 'abc'

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, google-colaboratory, abc

I'm trying to load python script from computer to google colab but is show me importError

[image]

Comment: Try `import abc;print(abc.__file__)` to see if its the script you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the file name `abc.py` for something else, like `testo.py` and it will work.

```
from google.colab import files

upload = files.upload()
```

check with `!ls`

testo.py

Try:

```
import testo

testo.myfunction()
```

## hello world !

Explanation: `abc` is a built-in module and you should not use that name for your modules. Check this question for more [info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031584/importing-from-builtin-library-when-module-with-same-name-exists).

Answer (score 1):

the abc module don't have my_function class/attribute/function/etc in the code this was example for reading the abc module go to python_home/Lib/abc.py and for reading the _abc module that written in C go to https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/_abc.c in github

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you import the built-in module [abc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#module-abc) which means **Abstract Base Classes** to create abstract classes so don't create the file with the name `abc.py`. *You can see all built-in modules in [Python Module Index](https://docs.python.org/3/py-modindex.html) which you cannot use as file names.

So, you should change `abc.py` to other name such as `greeting.py` then, importing `my_function` from `greeting.py` works without error as shown below:

```py
# "main.py"

     # ↓ Here
from greeting import my_function

my_function() # hello world
```

In addition, importing `def.py` below gets `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` error because `def` is a reserved word to define functions. *You can see all reserved words in [2.3.1 Keywords](https://docs.python.org/2.5/ref/keywords.html) and don't use `abcdef`'s `abc` and `def` as file names:

```py
import def # Error
```