# Python 3: Import of core module when local module exists with same name?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on a Python 3 project that unfortunately has a local module called `typing`, which clashes with the built in `typing` module.

The net result of this is there is no way for me to import the built in `typing` module as the local `typing` module is referenced first and ends up with the name `typing` in `sys.modules`.

I know I can rename the local module to something else and fix all the references and if there's no alternative I'll do that. The issue with that is I don't own the code so keeping my copy and the definitive copy in sync will get tricky if changes are made to that file by either me or the owners of the definitive copy.

I was wondering if there is a way using something like the `importlib` module to import the core `typing` module under a different name?

I tried a couple of things but they always fail because the local `typing` module is referenced first and ends up with the name `typing` in `sys.modules`. A few of the solutions in [Importing from builtin library when module with same name exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031584/importing-from-builtin-library-when-module-with-same-name-exists) looked promising but fail with recursion errors.

Comment: Ultimately that _is_ something that should be fixed upstream by renaming that module, since you're not the only one having this problem, surely…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct : the better solution would be to rename that module. Hacking around the import system may lead to sad headaches down the road, and more hackeries. Break the pattern : rename the module, make everyone happy.

A poor man's solution would be to change the [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path) order. If you manage to put the path `......./lib/site-packages` before the path to the directory containing your package containing the `typing` module, and if you do that **before any other module of the WHOLE Python program** imports any `typing`, it can work.

Here is my setup :

```
stack_overflow/
├─ annoying/
│  ├─ __init__.py
│  ├─ innocent.py
│  ├─ typing.py
│  ├─ main.py
```

```
# file: innocent.py
import typing
print("'typing' imported")

abc: typing.List[str] = ["a", "b", "c"]
```

```
# file: main.py

import sys

print(sys.path)

import innocent
```

and both `__init__.py` and `typing.py` are empty.

When I execute my main I get :

```
['C:\\PycharmProjects\\stack_overflow\\annoying', ... Python regular stuff ...]
'typing' imported
Traceback (most recent call last):
[...]
AttributeError: module 'typing' has no attribute 'List'
```

because the wrong file was imported, due to the `sys.path` order such that Python searched for `typing` in the `annoying` directory before to search in its `site-packages`.

I am now putting the path to the library at the end :

```
# file: main.py

import sys

print(sys.path)
annoying_library_index_in_syspath, annoying_library_path = next((i, path) for i, path in enumerate(sys.path))
sys.path.pop(annoying_library_index_in_syspath)
sys.path.append(annoying_library_path)
print(sys.path)

import innocent
```

which prints :

```
['C:\\PycharmProjects\\stack_overflow\\annoying', ... Python regular stuff ...]
[... Python regular stuff ..., 'C:\\PycharmProjects\\stack_overflow\\annoying']
'typing' imported
```

now that the order is reversed, Python imports `typing` from its `site-packages` in priority, and everything works as expected. But if I have an import (even transitive) to to module which imports a `typing` before I change the `sys.path`, it will fail again :

```
# file: main.py

import sys

import innocent  # raise AttributeError: module 'typing' has no attribute 'List'

print(sys.path)
annoying_library_index_in_syspath, annoying_library_path = next((i, path) for i, path in enumerate(sys.path))
sys.path.pop(annoying_library_index_in_syspath)
sys.path.append(annoying_library_path)
print(sys.path)

import innocent
```

But messing with `sys.path` is prone to errors, conflicts, pain and sadness. That's why is discouraged to reuse standard library names for user modules.   So please fix the file, it really is the best solution.