# How can I get the path of the higher level directory of the current .py file in python?

Tags: python

Say there's a directory hierarchy like this: `.../A/B/main.py`.

`main.py` is the file being executed, and I need to get the full path of folder `A`, how can I do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430372/how-to-get-full-path-of-current-directory-in-python

Answer (score 4):

Use the `os` module:

```
import os
a_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3:

```
from pathlib import Path

mypath = Path().absolute().parent.parent  # each '.parent' goes one level up - vary as required
print(mypath)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the path of the current directory, you can use:

```
import os
print os.path.realpath('.')
```

since `.` represents the current directory in the file system. So to get the path of the higher level directory, just replace `.` with `..`, which represents parent directory

```
import os
print os.path.realpath('..')
```

You can also use the `os.getcwd()` method to get the current working directory and then get its parent directory with the `..` representation.

Comment: Won't this give the dir one level higher? What if Parent is 3 or 4 levels deep?

Comment: in that case, we can still use the normal unix or windows path traversing. Just use `../..'to the the path of a directory, two levels higher.

Comment: The OP doesn't ask for the current directory - he wants the parent of the parent of the current executing file - using "." or cwd wont do that.