# Writing to a file from a python module

Tags: python, module, writetofile

I am currently trying to debug an app that I have not written myself. I have narrowed the problem down to a particular method that is imported from a module outside of the current script. I would like to step through this module by writing to a file at each step, however it doesn't seem to work.

I have a version of the app that is running correctly and when I write to a file from within the module, the script runs fine but no file is created. Am I missing something here?

Example

Script that I am debugging

```
from module import method

example code ...
method(data)   ---  where error occurs
more code ...
```

module.py

```
def method(data):
    file = open('filetowrite.txt','w')
    file.write('something ....')
    file.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not reinvent the wheel, use standard [logging](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) module.

Since you mentioned "I would like to step through this module" that's how you can do it with again standard [pdb](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) module.

Answer (score 0):

Your code for file writing looks fine. I would look at the path (the location) where the file is being written to.

Check out:

[How to get full path of current file's directory in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430372/how-to-get-full-path-of-current-directory-in-python)

Comment: also try opening it in `w+` instead of just `w` which means if it doesn't exist it will create it and not throw an error.