# error: (-215) !empty() in function detectMultiScale

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, image-recognition

I'm trying to learn cv2 in python 2.7, but when I run my code, in the specific part of it:

```
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
 eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_eye.xml')


img = cv2.imread('2015-05-27-191152.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
    img = cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
```

it returns this:

```
File "face_detection.py", line 11, in <module>
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
cv2.error: /home/arthurckl/Desktop/opencv-3.0.0-rc1/modules/objdetect/src/cascadedetect.cpp:1595: error: (-215) !empty() in function detectMultiScale
```

I tried to search the answer here but the best i could find is that I must be loading the face_cascade the wrong way... Any help?

Comment: your xml file was not found. try an absolute path like "/my/files/bla/cacade.xml"

Comment: @berak I replaced the original path for the one you suggested but the code returns the same error

Comment: can you verify that your image isnt empty (e.g. if not loaded correctly) by adding a test or image displaying?

Comment: @Micka I verified and my image is displayed... normally

Comment: what's the path of your xml files?

Comment: Oh I get it, I wrote the fila path the wrong way. Thanks for the help !

Comment: I have same issue and no matter how hard i tried i couldn't solved it. Can you tell us how you solved ? @arthurckl

Comment: i have samme issue but my xml file is also loaded

Comment: XML file needs to be loaded in the same path as of the existing python file....

Answer (score 182):

I had the same issue.

I didn't need to download anything else to solve this. CV2 had everything I needed.

Instead of trying to figure out where the `.xml` files are and hard coding the values, I used a property given by cv2.

From OP

```
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_eye.xml')
```

Becomes

```
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + 'haarcascade_eye.xml')
```

Comment: This should be marked as correct answer, would have saved me time.

Comment: What error did you get @VIVID? Was it with cv2.data.haarcascades or with cv2.CascadeClassifie?

Comment: @Mandelbrotter Here is my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63423843/error-empty-in-function-detectmultiscale

Comment: `pip install opencv-contrib-python` is needed to get `cv2.data`

Answer (score 76):

The XML or file is missing or the path to it is incorrect or the create_capture path is incorrect.

The paths in the opencv sample look like this:

```
cascade_fn = args.get('--cascade', "../../data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml")
nested_fn  = args.get('--nested-cascade', "../../data/haarcascades/haarcascade_eye.xml")

cam = create_capture(video_src, fallback='synth:bg=../data/lena.jpg:noise=0.05')
```

Answer (score 23):

I ran the same code. There are two things to note here.
1. Give the entire path of the .xml files.
2. Give a key press event instruction at the end.

Add this block of code at the end and run your file, worked for me:

```
k = cv2.waitKey(0)
if k == 27:         # wait for ESC key to exit
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
elif k == ord('s'): # wait for 's' key to save and exit
    cv2.imwrite('messigray.png',img)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

For example, my code looked like

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('C:\\opencv\\build\\etc\\haarcascades\\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('C:\\opencv\\build\\etc\\haarcascades\\haarcascade_eye.xml')

img = cv2.imread('lena.jpg')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
#faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray)

for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
    cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
    roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)
    for (ex,ey,ew,eh) in eyes:
        cv2.rectangle(roi_color,(ex,ey),(ex+ew,ey+eh),(0,255,0),2)

cv2.imshow('img',img)

k = cv2.waitKey(0)
if k == 27:         # wait for ESC key to exit
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
elif k == ord('s'): # wait for 's' key to save and exit
    cv2.imwrite('messigray.png',img)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

My output looked like this:

[image: ouput]

Comment: absolute path for me was wrong had to include CWD (C: Drive/projectdirectory/) i.e.  'C:/Flask/venv/Lib/site-packages/cv2/data/'

Answer (score 15):

You just need to add proper path of the `haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml` file **i.e.** you only have to add prefix (`cv2.data.haarcascades`)

```
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + 'haarcascade_eye.xml')
```

Answer (score 13):

The XML file is missing, you can get the file from the GitHub repository and place it in the same directory as your project. Link to the folder on GitHub is [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/data/haarcascades). Just download the file named *haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml*.
Actually, the file exists on your system. Just go to the **site-packages** folder of your python installation folder and check the cv2/data folder for the file

Answer (score 12):

Use the entire file path and use "\\" instead of "\" in the xml file path.

The file path should be as follows:

```
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('C:\\opencv\\build\\etc\\haarcascades\\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
```

instead of:

```
cascade_fn = args.get('--cascade', "..\..\data\haarcascades\haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml")
```

Answer (score 9):

no need to change the code

download that .xml file , then put the path of that file

it will solve the error (100%)

Answer (score 9):

This error means that the XML file could not be found. The library needs you to pass it the full path, even though you’re probably just using a file that came with the OpenCV library.

You can use the built-in [`pkg_resources` module](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html#resource-extraction) to automatically determine this for you. The following code looks up the full path to a file inside wherever the `cv2` module was loaded from:

```
import pkg_resources
haar_xml = pkg_resources.resource_filename(
    'cv2', 'data/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
```

For me this was `'/Users/andrew/.local/share/virtualenvs/foo-_b9W43ee/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cv2/data/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml'`; yours is guaranteed to be different. Just let python’s `pkg_resources` library figure it out.

```
classifier = cv2.CascadeClassifier(haar_xml)
faces = classifier.detectMultiScale(frame)
```

Success!

Answer (score 8):

If you are using Anaconda you should add the Anaconda path.

```
new_path = 'C:/Users/.../Anaconda/Library/etc/haarcascades/'

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(new_path + 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
```

Answer (score 5):

On OSX with a homebrew install the full path to the opencv folder should work:

```
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.4.0_1/share/OpenCV/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.4.0_1/share/OpenCV/haarcascades/haarcascade_eye.xml')
```

Take care of the version number in the path.

Answer (score 4):

Probably the `face_cascade` is empty. You can check if the variable is empty or not by typing following command:

```
face_cascade.empty()
```

If it is empty you will get `True` and this means your file is not available in the path you mentioned. 
Try to add complete path of xml file as follows:

```
r'D:\folder Name\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml'
```

Answer (score 4):

"\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\cv2\data\" I found the xml file in this path for Anaconda

Answer (score 4):

You can solve this problem by **placing XML in the same directory in which your main python file** (from where you tried to include this file) was placed. Now the next step is to use full path. For example

This will not work

```
front_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('./haarcascade_eye.xml')
```

Use full path, now it will work fine

```
front_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('/Users/xyz/Documents/project/haarcascade_eye.xml')
```

Answer (score 3):

You may find such kind of errors when you did not define the complete path of your XML file.
Try this one if you are using opencv3.1.0 in raspberrypi 3:

`faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('/home/pi/opencv-3.1.0/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')`

Answer (score 3):

I found this in some other answer but eventually worked for me when I added the two answers.

```
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + "haarcascade_eye.xml")

img = cv2.imread('image1.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your XML file was not found. Try using absolute paths like:

```
/path/to/my/file (Mac, Linux)
C:\\path\\to\\my\\file (Windows)
```

Answer (score 2):

the error may be due to, the required xml files has not been loaded properly. Search for the file `haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml`  by using the search engine of ur OS get the full path and put it as the argument to `cv2.CascadeClassifier` as string

Answer (score 2):

Please do not copy paste the content of xml file, because once you paste it to notepad it will be saved a s text file. So directly download the file from the given source.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem. but wrote the correct location.

```
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('./model/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
```

I figured out that i need to declare the full path to remove the error.

```
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('C:/pythonScript/Facial-Emotion-Detection/model/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
```

Comment: Solved my problem! Combine that with https://stackoverflow.com/a/3430395/3525780 and always get the current working directory

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs due to missing of xml files or incorrect path of xml file.

Please try the following code,

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_eye.xml')

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while 1:
    ret, img = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)

    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
        roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]

        eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)
        for (ex,ey,ew,eh) in eyes:
            cv2.rectangle(roi_color,(ex,ey),(ex+ew,ey+eh),(0,255,0),2)

    cv2.imshow('img',img)
    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == 27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with `opencv-python` and I used a virtual environment.
If it's your case, you should find the `xml` files at:

`/home/username/virtual_environment/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2/data/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml`

`/home/username/virtual_environment/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2/data/haarcascade_eye.xml`

Please be sure that you're using the absolute path. Otherwise, it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

The main idea of the solution as above mentioned: find the right path of the `.xml` file and use it to access the file correctly.

In my case, I installed the opencv in anoconda env, first direct to path of Anoconda, then

- find the path of `.xml` file by using:

  `$ find . -name 'haarcascade_eye.xml'`  (for example search the `haarcascade_eye.xml` file in current dir (.))
- Then use the return `path`:

`eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(path + 'haarcascade_eye.xml')`

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue. It seems correcting the path to XML makes this error to go away.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Though we thank you for your answer, it would be better if it provided additional value on top of the other answers. In this case, your answer does not provide additional value, since there are a plenty of answers already mentioned changing path to the XML.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be file path issue. I changed code like this and it worked.

```py
haar_face_filename = "D:\Sandbox\Github\Faces\haar_face.xml"
haar_cascade = cv.CascadeClassifier(haar_face_filename)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and was trying to use open cv in a springboot application where my xml files and images are in resources folder.
Trying to give path starting from `src` or a absolute path like `C:\a\b.xml` did not work.

Creating the file path dynamically with project root path worked.

```
String classifierPath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/main/resources/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface.xml";

// similarly for image paths
```

Answer (score 0):

Path needs to start with `/`, eg. `/file.xml`.