# OpenCV : Error (-215) Empty in detect multiscale (No solution Working)

Tags: python-2.7, opencv3.0

I had a look at different solutions to this same problem and didnt come up with anything. I tried changing the path to the XML file. Didnt help me.

Here is the code.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('opencv/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('opencv/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_eye.xml')

img = cv2.imread('face.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
    cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
    roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)
    for (ex,ey,ew,eh) in eyes:
        cv2.rectangle(roi_color,(ex,ey),(ex+ew,ey+eh),(0,255,0),2)

cv2.imshow('img',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

It still gives me the same error and that is

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (!empty()) in detectMultiScale, file /home/arpit/opencv/modules/objdetect/src/cascadedetect.cpp, line 1639
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "face.py", line 10, in <module>
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
cv2.error: /home/arpit/opencv/modules/objdetect/src/cascadedetect.cpp:1639: error: (-215) !empty() in function detectMultiScale
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error: (-215) !empty() in function detectMultiScale](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30508922/error-215-empty-in-function-detectmultiscale)

Comment: You see I did give the correct path of the _xml_ file and it still doesn't work. It worked for him in that answer.

Comment: Given that you get the same results, my guess is that you aren't using the FQPN that accurately points to the file... have you tried putting a copy of the XML itself directly in the same root folder instead?

Comment: Tried that. Still the same error