# Issue with OpenCV on Windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, haar-classifier

I'm not able to run this code in Python 3.5.2:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_eye.xml')

img = cv2.imread('test.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
    img = cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
    roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)
    for (ex,ey,ew,eh) in eyes:
        cv2.rectangle(roi_color,(ex,ey),(ex+ew,ey+eh),(0,255,0),2)

cv2.imshow('img',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

because of this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\python_stuff\head_tracker\still_more_testing.py", line 10, in <module>
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
cv2.error: D:\Build\OpenCV\opencv-3.2.0\modules\objdetect\src\cascadedetect.cpp:1681: error: (-215) !empty() in function cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale
```

There is no D:\ drive on my machine, there is no hidden D:\ drive either.

I've tried giving the full path to the cascade with `'\\'` and `'/'` to avoid escape characters.

Please tell me that path isn't hardcoded into OpenCV.

Comment: Looks a duplicate of [error-215-empty-in-function-detectmultiscale](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30508922/error-215-empty-in-function-detectmultiscale)

Comment: actually this is happening under python 3.5.2... none of the solutions offered for 2.7 worked for me

Answer (score 0):

If you can sure you site right,try to assign an address to a variable,and use

```
detector = cv2.CascadeClassifier(path1)
```