# opencv cascade.detectMultiScale creates error: (-215) !empty()

Tags: python, opencv

I am following [this](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/d7/d8b/tutorial_py_face_detection.html) tutorial to understand haar features. While writing following code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_eye.xml')
img = cv2.imread('Sachin.jpeg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
```

getting following error:

```
File "<ipython-input-6-0b479e459b0f>", line 1, in <module>
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)

    error: /home/travis/miniconda/conda-bld/conda_1486587069159/work/opencv-3.1.0/modules/objdetect/src/cascadedetect.cpp:1639: error: (-215) !empty() in function detectMultiScale
```

(Sachin is the image i downloaded from google, of size (237,237,3) and after converting gray it is (237,237) with min=23, max=210. I am using opencv 3.1.0 with python 3.6, installed using command **conda install -c menpo opencv3**. i am trying for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30508922/error-215-empty-in-function-detectmultiscale) solution but unable to find xml file in my desktop. How to solve problem.

Comment: How did you install OpenCV ?

Comment: I already mention this in question. conda install -c menpo opencv3

Comment: Are you working on Linux ? or Windows ?

Comment: Linux (ubuntu) 16.04 version LTS

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to specify the full paths to the XML files for Haar Cascade.

On Ubuntu 16.04, these files can be found in `/usr/share/opencv/haarcascades`.

Comment: I am not finding this location /home/nd/share/opencv/haarcascades. after changing same error again

Comment: Why `/home/nd` ? I said `/usr`. Are you new to Ubuntu ?

Comment: I change line 3 and 4 i.e. face_cascade and eye_cascade lines but how can i insert /usr/share/opencv/haarcascades in last line i.e. faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5), and error is in this line

Comment: The program crashing at one line doesn't necessarily mean that the error can be found at that precise line.

Comment: `import numpy as np
import cv2
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('/usr/share/opencv/haarcascades_frontalface_default.xml')
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('/usr/share/opencv/haarcascades_eye.xml')
img = cv2.imread('Sachin.jpeg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)`   and getting same error

Comment: You still don't have the right path... Did you read my answer ? It should be `'/usr/share/opencv/haarcascades/haarcascades_fronta‌​lface_default.xml'`

Comment: Sry for my mistake. But now i modified the code to `import numpy as np 
import cv2 
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('/usr/share/opencv/haarcascades/haarcascades_fronta‌​lface_d‌​efault.xml') 
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('/usr/share/opencv/haarcascades/haarcascades_eye.xm‌​l') 
img = cv2.imread('Sachin.jpeg') 
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 
faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)` and still getting same error

Comment: Can you open a terminal and run these commands:
`cd /usr && find -name haarcascade*`
This should give you the location of the xml files. Make sure the path is right. If nothing appears, then the files are not there and you'll need to search for them somewhere else or verify your OpenCV installation

Comment: I exactly type `cd /usr && find -name haarcascade*` this on my terminal. nothing appears. SO i have to reinstall opencv. what do you mean by `make sure the path is right`  ?

Comment: Other simple solution is to download the haar files directly and put them in the same folder you are running your program on, that way you don't need to put the whole path and your program will work. That will also make your program work if you change your env.

Comment: @Sunreef  thnx. Now your given solution works for me.

Answer (score 2):

You should be in the same directory as the xml file . Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You need to give **full path** for `haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml` and `haarcascade_eye.xml`.

use `cv2.data.haarcascades` which will give you the path.

```
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(
    cv2.data.haarcascades+'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(
    cv2.data.haarcascades+'haarcascade_eye.xml')
```