# OpenCV. detectMultiScale() function return error

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm new to OpenCV. Took an example from official documentation. When I try to run the code, an error pops up. When you try to run the code, an error pops up when you call the function detectMultiScale ()

```
Mat image;
image = imread("1.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
imshow("cam", image);
// Load Face cascade (.xml file)
CascadeClassifier face_cascade;
face_cascade.load("C:/opencv/sources/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml");

// Detect faces
std::vector<Rect> faces;

Mat frame_gray;
cvtColor(image, frame_gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
equalizeHist(frame_gray, frame_gray);
face_cascade.detectMultiScale(frame_gray, faces, 1.1, 2, 0 | CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30));
```

Tell me how to solve this problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFsx4.png)

Answer (score 0):

It is because of your xml file path, be sure about that your path directory is true. I checked your code in my pc and worked well. Search your "haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml" file in your pc and copy it to your code.

The same problem was also mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30508922/error-215-empty-in-function-detectmultiscale)