# Assertion fail with Open CV

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I'm new to openCV and am trying to get openCV to work my USB webcam on Win7 with Python 3.8. I've got the basic tutorial from [here](https://github.com/gigafide/simple_opencv_pi_face_detector/blob/master/face_tracker_usb.py) modified from Raspberry Pi cam by the same author [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uI8oBS7iJD0).
which is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import time
import numpy as np
import cv2


#point to the haar cascade file in the directory
cascPath = "haarcascade.xml"
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascPath)

#start the camera
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

#give camera time to warm up
time.sleep(0.1)

#start video frame capture loop
while True:
  # take the frame, convert it to black and white, and look for facial features
  ret, frame = video_capture.read()

  gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

  # use appropriate flag based on version of OpenCV
  if int(cv2.__version__.split('.')[0]) >= 3:
    cv_flag = cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE
  else:
    cv_flag = cv2.cv.CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE

  faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
    gray,
    scaleFactor=1.1,
    minNeighbors=5,
    minSize=(30, 30),
    flags=cv_flag
  )

  #for each face, draw a green rectangle around it and append to the image
  for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
    cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

  #display the resulting image
  cv2.imshow('Video', frame)

  #set "q" as the key to exit the program when pressed
  if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break


# clear the stream capture
video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

It should run out of the box, but I get the error below and I'm not sure why. CV_flag and gray have data and the other parameters are filled. Any ideas.

```
C:\Users\Ghoul>py D:\LearnPython\open_cv_face_track_test.py -3.8
[ WARN:0] global C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (674) 
SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB
 terminating async callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\LearnPython\open_cv_face_track_test.py", line 31, in <module>
    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.2) C:\projects\opencv- 
python\opencv\modules\objdetect\src\cascadedetect.cpp:1689: error: (-215:Ass
ertion failed) !empty() in function 'cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale'
```

Comment: Sounds like it is this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30508922/771848

Comment: you have to use full path to `xml` - lucky there is variable with folder name `cv2.data.haarcascades` - `cv2.CascadeClassifier( os.path.join(cv2.data.haarcascades, cascPath) )`

Comment: Turns out that haarcascade.xml doesn't exist for 2.2 I'm using haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml instead. Let's hope that's ok.

Answer (score 1):

The `faceCascade` classifier is empty, which means it was unable to retrieve the classifier from the path provided.

You can replace the line

```
cascPath = "haarcascade.xml"
```

with:

```
cascPath = '../../haarcascade.xml'
```

where you provide the full path of the xml file for `cascPath`.