# Python OpenCV - CascadeClassifier Haarcascade detectMultiScale() not working

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, haar-classifier

I am learning **OpenCV** through Python v3.8.5 since last few days, got stuck in **CascadeClassifier** on **Facedetection**. Following the same code as the tutor : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LopYA64KmdE Timestamp: 08:40

I have the image and haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml files in the resources folder

Still, I don't get any output for this below code. I tried changing images files too but still no output. When I tried printing it print till 'foo1'. So I suspect the issue is around detectMultiScale() method.

Here is my code:

```
import cv2

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('resources\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

# img = cv2.imread('resources\\lena.jpg')
# img = cv2.imread('D:\photos\house\DSCF2736 copy.jpg')
img = cv2.imread('resources\\messi5.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

print('foo1')
faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray,1.1,4)
print('foo2')

for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
    cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+h,y+w),(0,255,0),2)

cv2.imshow('out',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I am using Windows7 32 bit PC. Is this due to OS support issue? Please let me know the solution.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried changing a picture for testing?

Comment: @August, Yes I tried various clear clarity visible frontal face images

Comment: Then it is obvious that there is a problem with your `haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml`, you can download a `haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml` from the Internet to try.[haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml)

Comment: I have the right file in the right place bro. Also, I checked all the other answers before posting this question. Nothing seems relevant to where I am stuck. So I posted here.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should write `[x,y,w,h,]` or `(x,y,w,h)` instead of `x,y,w,h` in the `for` loop because the given `detectMultiScale` function generates a list containing multiple `[x,y,w,h]` elements for every face and lists can be stored only in lists objects or tuples.

Comment: oh, I corrected it in my code and in the question. Thanks for that.But No output still. Since, Python is an interpreted language, it got stuck 2 lines before.

Comment: Then try by removing the cv2.destroyAllWindows line at the end of code because it closes all open windows in opencv when this line happens to execute.

Answer (score 0):

It's in the resources folder, but is the current working directory properly set relative to the calling script. There's a common issue when the path to this xml file is not properly set for one or another reason - try with absolute path or copy it in the folder with the script and calling from command line in that folder.

See:
[OpenCV Facial Detection come ups with this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65649556/opencv-facial-detection-come-ups-with-this-error/65649802#65649802)

Comment: yes, I added the xml file and image inside the resource folder which is in current working directory only

Comment: face_cascade = 
 cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades+"haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")

I tried this way, but still no output