# opencv -215:Assertion failed while trying to print face coorrdenates

Tags: python, opencv

I am not able to print the face coordinates and getting errors

The code works fine till that line. I tried fixing it in many ways like using location instead of the name of the picture.

```py
import cv2
trained_face_data= cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontface_default.xml')
# the source pic
img=cv2.imread('D:\\opencv\\CUTE  2.png')
#img=cv2.imread('CUTE  2.png')
#convert to gray
Gray_img= cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
face_coordinates = trained_face_data.detectMultiScale(Gray_img)
#showng an image
#cv2.imshow('Clever Programmer Face Detector', Gray_img)
print(face_coordinates)
# wait to excute
cv2.waitKey()
```

the Erroe message is
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.3) C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-sn_xpupm\opencv\modules\objdetect\src\cascadedetect.cpp:1689: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !empty() in function 'cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale'

What is the cause of the error?

Comment: Are you sure `Gray_img` is not `None`? BTW, avoid posting error messages as image. Copy-n-paste them here.

Comment: when i excute cv2.imshow('Clever Programmer Face Detector', Gray_img), it works with no error

Comment: By "it works", you mean the image is shown? Please, update the question with the full traceback. Then, delete the image.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error: (-215) !empty() in function detectMultiScale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30508922/error-215-empty-in-function-detectmultiscale)

Comment: yes the image is converted to gray and shown

Comment: i changed the first line to 
trained_face_data=cv2.CascadeClassifier('D:\\opencv\\haarcascade_frontface_default.xml')
to make sure that it take the right path, and still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the name of trained file, please:
*haarcascade_frontface_default* **or** *haarcascade_front**al**face_default* ?

And also where is your xml file? check its path again.

> **ProjectFolder**
> -script.py
> -xml file
> -im.jpg

```py
import sys
import cv2

pth=sys.path[0] # Returns the "ProjectFolder" path
cs= cv2.CascadeClassifier(pth+'/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

im=cv2.imread(pth+'/im.jpg')
gry= cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

data = cs.detectMultiScale(gry)
print(data)

cv2.waitKey()
```

Its working well in my case:

> [[ 91 303 573 573]]

Comment: the path was correct but I forgot to write "al"