# Why does detectMultiScale() throw error: (-215:Assertion failed) !empty()

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, face-detection

I learning opencv and I'm stuck on this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/nicolas/Pulpit/programowanie/python/CV/opecv.py", line 10, in <module>
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(img)

error: OpenCV(4.5.5) /io/opencv/modules/objdetect/src/cascadedetect.cpp:1689: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !empty() in function 'detectMultiScale'
```

I tried every possible solution from here:
First the gray martix isn't empty, second the paths are good and don't toss errors,
but I still don't know what is wrong...
And that's my code:

```
import cv2 as cv 

img = cv2.imread('img/face.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('/home/nicolas/Pulpit/programowanie/python/CV/databases/haar_face.xml')

faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray)

for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
    cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)

cv2.imshow('img',img)

k = cv2.waitKey(0)
if k == 27:         # wait for ESC key to exit
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: It appears that `face_cascade` is empty. The classifier file was not loaded properly.

Comment: so what you propose?

Comment: 'cause I made xml file correctly, I suppose... and path is right

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error: (-215) !empty() in function detectMultiScale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30508922/error-215-empty-in-function-detectmultiscale)

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz i don't know why, but when I switched
`'/home/nicolas/Pulpit/programowanie/python/CV/databases/haar_face.xml'` to
`'/home/nicolas/Pulpit/programowanie/python/CV/databases/haar_face`

Answer (score 0):

Okey guys, I made it! I'm using linux, and in paths there are no extensions, so path should be 'haar_face' not 'haar_face.xml'.

Comment: why would you create an XML file without a `.xml` extension? that's just confusing. no, "this is linux" is not the reason for *data* files to become unrecognizable. linux merely doesn't need `.exe` to think something's executable, but that's not the issue here.

Comment: but if code is working without ".xml" in path, it seems to be the issue