# Why does my python bash subprocess show a cant open file error?

Tags: python, bash

I have a python tile menu script where a subprocess executes a bash shell:

```
    # excute shell script
    subprocess.call([self.path + '/pimenu.sh'] + actions)
```

and in the shell I have:

```
   python ./to/file/name/"$*".py
```

but when the python script which is found and executed returns an error as it cant find the folder with the images in.:

```
  pygame.error: Couldn't open ./file/name/image.jpg
```

I am assuming it is looking in the folder the menu script is in, how can I give python or bash the correct path to the scripts resources?

Comment: have you given the full path?

Comment: it finds the .py file but not the folder thats the images are in.

Comment: its the variable to call the function

Comment: an example: if action = 'game1' then game1.py is called

Comment: why is one path  `./to/file/name/` and the other `./file/name/`? I would try passing full paths and see how that goes

Comment: Is this question not useful or legitimate? Why the down vote?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a path finding built in python's `os` package into the scripts `./to/file/name/"$*".py` like this:

```
import os
print os.getcwd()
```

It is good enought described into the next SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3430395/2261861