# How to use shutil.rmtree without specifying a path

Tags: python, python-3.x, shutil

How can I get `shutil.rmtree()` to run on the folder it is in? I know I can just give it the path but I want it to be dynamic so I can move it across folders and it will still run without having to edit the path.

I haven't tried anything because I don't know what to try.

Comment: Do you mean the current working directory or the directory the current file is in? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430372/how-to-get-full-path-of-current-files-directory-in-python to get the path dynamically

Comment: thanks, and i meant the directory the current file is in

Comment: can you elaborate on the purpose of this code? looks like a malware to me...

Comment: to save time when i need to delete a load of things. like most programs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution would be just these two lines of code.

```
import shutil
shutil.rmtree('./')
```

It deletes the content of the current folder, and itself.

Note. Be careful with this, as with my experience running this, the files do not appear in the recycle bin.

<sup>**I cannot be liable for any unwanted loss of files.**</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Get the path of the directory the current file is in dynamically. Note this will delete the current file too!

```
import os
import shutil

path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
shutil.rmtree(path)
```