# Open file in the same directory

Tags: json, python-3.x, file

I've an `__init__.py` file in my `Database` package and I would want to read some information from a configuration file (`config.json`) in the same directory.

I've tried this code:

```
with open("config.json", 'r') as json_data:
    data = json.load(json_data)
print(data)
```

but i got this error:

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'config.json'`

Where is the mistake?

Comment: `import os ; print(os.getcwd())` to see where your script is actually running from

Comment: Working directory =/= directory where script is located

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get full path of current file's directory in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430372/how-to-get-full-path-of-current-files-directory-in-python)

Comment: `with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),"config.json"), 'r') as json_data:`

Comment: Resolved. Thank you all.