# How to access test suite directory path inside the test code

Tags: python, pytest

I need to access current test suite Directory path inside the test code. So as to access some files in the test suite directory:

Example:

```
/home/stu/myproj/pytest
                    |_test_abc.py
                    |_perf.sh
                    |_conftest.py
```

I need to get the path of  perf.sh(/home/student/pytest/) inside the test_abc.py. Since i do not know from which directory py.test command will be run, and the user can move(git clone) myproj to any directory. I can't use hardcoded path.

since the test suite directory will be passed as parameter , is there a way access this directory path and use it inside my test code (test_abc.py).

Comment: This is a duplicate indeed.  Please see my reply to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430372/how-to-get-full-path-of-current-files-directory-in-python/50098973#50098973

Answer (score -1):

Below code may help you.

```
import os
import inspect

# find out the directory of current script
directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))
# make a full path of the testfile(perf.sh)
the_filename = os.path.join(directory, 'perf.sh')
if os.path.isfile(the_filename):
    print 'Found the file'
else:
    print 'Failed to find the file'
```