# Creating directory on relative path in Python and running in absolute path

Tags: python, linux, directory

I have the following python script (script.py):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os

os.makedirs('./downloads/')
```

Which simply creates a directory named 'downloads' in the directory, where the script.py file is located.

Now I want this program to be run as a cronjob in linux. So the command for that is:

```
./home/pi/application/script.py
```

The folder, the program creates should be created under '/home/pi/application/' but it is created in the root directory '/'

How can I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get full path of current file's directory in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430372/how-to-get-full-path-of-current-files-directory-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

To get the path where `script.py` is rather than the path from where you call the script (working directory) you can use:

```
os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

In you example, the previous command would return `/home/pi/application/` (if that is the full path).