# When loading an image in Pygame, I get the error "No file found"

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

I am learning pygame and getting errors.

Whenever I want to put a background image in my window I get an error `No file found`. While the image name is appropriate.

I'm using Windows PC

Hope this community helps me and motivates me to learn more.

here's my code

```python
import pygame

pygame.init()

window_width = 400
window_height = 400

size = (window_height, window_width)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

pygame.display.set_caption("Hello_World")

background_image = pygame.image.load("motivation.png").convert()

while True:
        screen.blit(background_image, [0, 0])
```

Comment: A good title uniquely describes your specific problem. Everyone asking a question wants help, so "Please Help!" doesn't add anything useful, and since there are _lots_ of questions with the pygame tag, mentioning it in the title doesn't make your question unique either. *"File not found" loading images with correct name* is one example of what a more descriptive title might look like.

Answer (score 1):

The image file path has to be relative to the current working directory. The working directory is possibly different to the directory of the python file.

See further [pygame.image.load('sprite/test_bg.jpg'): pygame.error: Couldn't open sprite/test_bg.jpg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58177145/pygame-image-loadsprite-test-bg-jpg-pygame-error-couldnt-open-sprite-test).

---

You have to handle the events in the application loop. See [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get) respectively [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump):

> For each frame of your game, you will need to make some sort of call to the event queue. This ensures your program can internally interact with the rest of the operating system.

See further [PyGame window not responding after a few seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20165492/pygame-window-not-responding-after-a-few-seconds/61409221#61409221)