# Pygame animation list index continuously goes out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x, animation, pygame

I followed a clear code tutorial to make a platformer and ended up finishing it, however one thing always continously messed up. That being the animation, at times the game just would not run and would only run in debug mode due to the animation list being out of index which makes no sense to me since every item in the list is accounted for. Below is my player.py which has all of the functions and such that the video mentions. If more information is needed I will gladly provide it. (the animation part is specifically erroring at self.image = self.animations['idle'][self.frame_index])

```
import pygame 
from support import import_folder

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,pos,surface,create_jump_particles):
        super().__init__()
        self.import_character_assets()
        self.frame_index = 0
        self.animation_speed = 0.15
        self.image = self.animations['idle'][self.frame_index]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = pos)
        
        # dust particles 
        self.import_dust_run_particles()
        self.dust_frame_index = 0
        self.dust_animation_speed = 0.15
        self.display_surface = surface
        self.create_jump_particles = create_jump_particles

        # player movement
        self.direction = pygame.math.Vector2(0,0)
        self.speed = 8
        self.gravity = 0.8
        self.jump_speed = -16

        # player status
        self.status = 'idle'
        self.facing_right = True
        self.on_ground = False
        self.on_ceiling = False
        self.on_left = False
        self.on_right = False

    def import_character_assets(self):
        character_path = '../graphics/character/'
        self.animations = {'idle':[],'run':[],'jump':[],'fall':[]}

        for animation in self.animations.keys():
            full_path = character_path + animation
            self.animations[animation] = import_folder(full_path)

    def import_dust_run_particles(self):
        self.dust_run_particles = import_folder('../graphics/character/dust_particles/run')

    def animate(self):
        animation = self.animations[self.status]

        # loop over frame index 
        self.frame_index += self.animation_speed
        if self.frame_index >= len(animation):
            self.frame_index = 0

        image = animation[int(self.frame_index)]
        if self.facing_right:
            self.image = image
        else:
            flipped_image = pygame.transform.flip(image,True,False)
            self.image = flipped_image

        # set the rect
        if self.on_ground and self.on_right:
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect(bottomright = self.rect.bottomright)
        elif self.on_ground and self.on_left:
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect(bottomleft = self.rect.bottomleft)
        elif self.on_ground:
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect(midbottom = self.rect.midbottom)
        elif self.on_ceiling and self.on_right:
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topright = self.rect.topright)
        elif self.on_ceiling and self.on_left:
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = self.rect.topleft)
        elif self.on_ceiling:
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect(midtop = self.rect.midtop)

    def run_dust_animation(self):
        if self.status == 'run' and self.on_ground:
            self.dust_frame_index += self.dust_animation_speed
            if self.dust_frame_index >= len(self.dust_run_particles):
                self.dust_frame_index = 0

            dust_particle = self.dust_run_particles[int(self.dust_frame_index)]

            if self.facing_right:
                pos = self.rect.bottomleft - pygame.math.Vector2(6,10)
                self.display_surface.blit(dust_particle,pos)
            else:
                pos = self.rect.bottomright - pygame.math.Vector2(6,10)
                flipped_dust_particle = pygame.transform.flip(dust_particle,True,False)
                self.display_surface.blit(flipped_dust_particle,pos)

    def get_input(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.direction.x = 1
            self.facing_right = True
        elif keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.direction.x = -1
            self.facing_right = False
        else:
            self.direction.x = 0

        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE] and self.on_ground:
            self.jump()
            self.create_jump_particles(self.rect.midbottom)

    def get_status(self):
        if self.direction.y < 0:
            self.status = 'jump'
        elif self.direction.y > 1:
            self.status = 'fall'
        else:
            if self.direction.x != 0:
                self.status = 'run'
            else:
                self.status = 'idle'

    def apply_gravity(self):
        self.direction.y += self.gravity
        self.rect.y += self.direction.y

    def jump(self):
        self.direction.y = self.jump_speed

    def update(self):
        self.get_input()
        self.get_status()
        self.animate()
        self.run_dust_animation()
```

I've tried everything, I've even gone to his website and downloaded his prototype and tried adding my own files to it and it still returns the same error. Whats supposed to be happening is that my character does an animation depending on which state they are in.

Comment: You have to set the working directory. See [Could not open resource file, pygame error: "FileNotFoundError: No such file or directory."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58177145/could-not-open-resource-file-pygame-error-filenotfounderror-no-such-file-or)

Answer (score 0):

So it's likely that the code is not loading any of the animation frames for the 'idle' character animation.

The initialisation code first loads all the assets:

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,pos,surface,create_jump_particles):
        super().__init__()
        self.import_character_assets()
```

Where `self.import_character_assets()` is:

```
def import_character_assets(self):
    character_path = '../graphics/character/'
    self.animations = {'idle':[],'run':[],'jump':[],'fall':[]}

    for animation in self.animations.keys():
        full_path = character_path + animation
        self.animations[animation] = import_folder(full_path)
```

Which is iterating through 'idle', 'run', 'jump', 'fall', loading images from '../graphics/character/idle', '../graphics/character/run', etc. into a dictionary-of-lists.

We don't have the code for `import_folder()`, but it's obviously  intended to load some set of images.

After importing, the `self.animations` dictionary is expected to have at least a single image in `self.animations['idle']`.  This is because the `__init__()` is defaulting to 'idle', and index `0`:

```
    self.frame_index = 0
    self.animation_speed = 0.15
    self.image = self.animations['idle'][self.frame_index]  # <<-- HERE, 0
```

So we can conclude that because we know, `self.animations['idle']` is out of bounds, even on `[0]`, no images were loaded.

Check that there are images available for this.  Or maybe the filenames are not what's expected (e.g.: .jpg, not .png), or some other file-system error (e.g.: read only, zero byte files, ... ).  Maybe the load-path is incorrect?

It might be a good idea to check the load, and write an error:

```
def import_character_assets(self):
    character_path = '../graphics/character/'
    self.animations = {'idle':[],'run':[],'jump':[],'fall':[]}

    for animation in self.animations.keys():
        full_path = character_path + animation
        self.animations[animation] = import_folder(full_path)
        # check we loaded something
        if ( len( self.animations[animation] ) == 0 ):
            print( "Failed to load any animations for \"" + animation + "\" type" )
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the response! I'll make sure to do so when I work on it later tonight

Answer (score -1):

You should put the full path here instead of "..":

character_path = '../graphics/character/'