# How can you save images not drive specific in python?

Tags: python, exe, cx-freeze

So I made a basic python script and converted it into an exe. When I made the script into an exe I was so excited and wanted to send it to my uncle .I compressed the script and a few files and images into a zip and
sent it to my uncle .When he opened the exe it failed and he realised that the error could be because I saved the images on drive D:/, when he unzipped the zip file it didn't save on his D drive.

While the exe works my computer it doesn't work on his so I'm trying to find out how to make the images not drive specific.

Comment: rather than saving on D, save on current folder, using just the filename and not the full path, maybe that will sort the problem out?

Comment: I used cx_Freeze to create the windows exe

Comment: and when I try  to do what Je Je says it writes FileNotFoundError: No such file or directory

Comment: `import os` `os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))`. See [Could not open resource file, pygame error: "FileNotFoundError: No such file or directory."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58177145/could-not-open-resource-file-pygame-error-filenotfounderror-no-such-file-or)

Comment: I try to do what you said but it gives me this error:

Comment: File "d:\space_invaders\code\code.py", line 22, in <module>
    man = pygame.transform.scale(man, (80,80))
TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not None

Comment: here is the code:

Comment: man = os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath("stickman.png")))
man = pygame.transform.scale(man, (80,80))
man_loc = man.get_rect()
man_loc.center = man_x,man_y

ship = os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath("ship1.png")))
ship = pygame.transform.scale(ship, (120,80))
ship_loc = ship.get_rect()
ship_loc.center = 200,50

ship1 = os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath("ship1.png"))) 
ship1 = pygame.transform.scale(ship1, (120,80))
ship1_loc = ship1.get_rect()
ship1_loc.center = 320,50

Comment: ship2 = os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath("ship1.png"))) 
ship2 = pygame.transform.scale(ship2, (120,80))
ship2_loc = ship2.get_rect()
ship2_loc.center = 440,50

Comment: I never told you to us it like that. Read [Could not open resource file, pygame error: "FileNotFoundError: No such file or directory."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58177145/could-not-open-resource-file-pygame-error-filenotfounderror-no-such-file-or). Just put `import os` and  `os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))` at the  begin of your code, but do not change anything else.

Comment: I did it what is next

Comment: Now the " FileNotFoundError: No such file or directory" error should be gone.

Comment: When adding details, information or other update to your question whether requested or not, do not add this in comments. Always EDIT and update the original question.

Answer (score 0):

#create directory like this

```
application folder name (folder)
        └── your application.exe

        └── imgs (folder)
                |__ image.png
                |__ image2.png
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

## in script use file paths like this

image1_path = "imgs\image.png"

image2_path = "imgs\image2.png"