# Pygame opening and immediately closing

Tags: pygame

I am working through the book Python Crash Course and have gotten stuck trying to use Pygame. Here's my code:

alien_invasion.py

```
import sys

import pygame

from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship

class AlienInvasion:
    """ Overall class to manage game assets and behavior"""

    def __init__(self):
        """ Initialize the game and create game resources"""
        pygame.init()
        self.settings = Settings()

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.settings.screen_width, self.settings.screen_height))
        pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

        self.ship = Ship(self)

    def run_game(self):
        """Start the main loop for the game"""
        while True:
            # Watch for keyboard and mouse events
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    sys.exit()

            # Redraw the screen during each pass through the loop
            self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)
            self.ship.blitme()

            # Make the most recently drawn screen visible
            pygame.display.flip()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Make a game instance and run the game
    ai = AlienInvasion()
    ai.run_game()
```

ship.py

```
import pygame

class Ship:
    """ A class to manage the ship"""

    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        """Initialize the ship and set its starting position"""
        self.screen = ai_game.screen
        self.screen_rect = ai_game.screen.get_rect()

        # Load the ship image and get its rect
        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/rocket.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        

        #Start each new ship at the bottom center of the screen
        self.rect.midbottom = self.screen_rect.midbottom

    def blitme(self):
        """ Draw the ship at its current location"""
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

settings.py

```
class Settings:
    """ Store all the settings for Alien Invasions"""

    def __init__(self):
        """ Initialize the game's settings"""
        # Screen Settings
        self.screen_width = 1200
        self.screen_height = 800
        self.bg_color = (230,230,230)
```

According to the book, opening alien_invasion.py should pull up a window with a gray background and the image rocket.bmp centered at the bottom. Instead, the pygame window opens for a split second before closing immediately.

Each individual module compiles with no errors. After reading other stack exchange posts with similar issues, I tried double and triple checking the while loop for indentation errors, and I'm fairly sure that the indenting is correct. The issue seems to be with the Ship class because if I remove lines 19 and 31 from alien_invasion.py
`self.ship = Ship(self)`
...
`self.ship.blitme()`

then the program works as expected: it opens a pygame window with a gray background without the rocket ship image (and doesn't close).

I have gone through the Ship class multiple times checking for errors and can't seem to find any. I have copied everything character for character from the book *except* for the name of the image since I had to download my own image for the rocket. I used [this one](https://pixabay.com/vectors/rocket-vector-space-launch-2442125/). The file is definitely in the right directory because ship.py compiles without an error. At first I used the original image which is a PNG and simply called the convert() method, i.e. line 12 of ship.py used to be

`self.image = pygame.image.load('images/rocket.png').convert()`

Since this was the only difference from the textbook, I tried manually converting the image to BMP, but this did not fix the issue. I am at a loss at what else I could try changing.  I'd appreciate any help! I am very new to programming so it's possible there is an obvious issue which I have overlooked.

Comment: I assume you're running your program by double-clicking on the .py file.  Instead, run it from a terminal window; that way, you have time to see the error message that is almost certainly being produced.

Comment: Opening it with terminal makes it work perfectly, thank you! Any idea why double-clicking it doesn't work? And moreover, why does double clicking still work when the Ship class is removed?

Comment: Double-clicking is likely starting your program with a different current working directory, one in which the relative pathname `images/rocket.bmp` does not exist.  You either need to explicitly set the working directory, or use an absolute pathname for the file.

Comment: You have to set the working directory. See [Could not open resource file, pygame error: "FileNotFoundError: No such file or directory."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58177145/could-not-open-resource-file-pygame-error-filenotfounderror-no-such-file-or)