# Can't open a file when not running from __main__

Tags: python, file, module

This is my file tree:

```
run.py
foo/
    file.py
    foo.json
```

In `file.py` there is the following code:

```
import json

print(json.load(open('foo.json')))
```

In `run.py` there is the following code:

```
import foo.foo as foo
```

When running `run.py` I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 1, in <module>
    import foo.foo as foo
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\foo\foo.py", line 3, in <module>
    print(json.load(open('foo.json')))
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'foo.json'
```

How do I run `run.py` without getting that error and without `run.py` being in the same directory. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Change `'foo.json'` to `'foo/foo.json'`? or to the absolute path if you want to be able to run `run.py` from any location

Comment: what do you mean? can you make an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the absolute path
`os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'your file')`

In your file put the path from the top of the project, should be `/foo/foo.json`

Answer (score 2):

As @DeepSpace mentioned can you try setting `foo.json` to `foo/foo.json`? As the error indicates it is not able to find such file called 'foo.json` so it's likely to do with the file not being located.

You can also run it with an Absolute path (read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430372/how-do-i-get-the-full-path-of-the-current-files-directory)). Try getting the current working directory and setting the file_name as the argument.

**Python 2 and 3**

For the directory of the script being run:

```
import os
os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

If you mean the current working directory:

```
import os
os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())
```

Read more on this from the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html)