# Python : how to get path to a folder knowing folder name?

Tags: python, directory, path, operating-system

Knowing the name of my folder "folder_name",

how can i easily get in python (script not in the same folder) the absolute path "/home/user/../path/to/../folder_name" ?

Comment: please check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430372/how-do-i-get-the-full-path-of-the-current-files-directory

Comment: `pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.absolute()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os

directory = os.path.dirname(__file__)
file_path = os.path.join(directory, './filename.extension')
print(file_path)
```