# How to get absolute path of python file REGARDLESS of where it is run from

Tags: python-3.x, path, pathlib

I'm trying to get the absolute path to a python file that I run from terminal regardless of WHERE I am in the filesystem when I run that file. So far I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3430372/6382242), but the answers using `pathlib` don't work, as I'm about to demonstrate:

contents of `path_test.py`

```
import pathlib
path_ = pathlib.Path(__file__).absolute().parent
print(path_)
```

if you call `python3 path_test.py` from the same directory, or any directory *above*, it prints out the expected output:

`/home/zaid/misc/import_test`

now create a directory in the same directory `mkdir dir` that has `path_test.py`, and `cd` into it, now call `python3 ../path_test.py`

the output is:

`/home/zaid/misc/import_test/dir/..`

which ***breaks*** python's `importlib`'s functionality and is ***NOT*** the expected output.

Comment: `import os; os.path.abspath(__file__)`

Comment: this works! I've been searching for hours for a valid method. But this is only a partial solution, the full solution would do `import os; import pathlib; pathlib.Path(os.path.abspath(__file__))` to make it into a path variable to be able to take its parents.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is, from some quick testing:

```
import os
import pathlib
path_ = pathlib.Path(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```