# How to get Blender script path that is running

Tags: python, blender

[How do I get the full path of the current file's directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430372/how-do-i-get-the-full-path-of-the-current-files-directory)

Yes, I already tried these methods. They all give me the folder that contains Blender.exe
which is `D:\program\Blender 2.90`

And what I supposed to get is `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.90\scripts\addons\someAddonFolder` right?

Is something changed in version 2.9?
Without the Blender environment, I mean run under normal Python. Methods from that topic all work well.
Did I miss something?

The old way I made the script work is by putting .blend .json .py all together in the same folder.
and refer to the relative path using `//`

Comment: Which "current file"? The .blend file? Or a .py file? Which one?

Comment: current py, sorry not say it clearly

Comment: I also want get the python path which send to `blender --python a.py`. I want get the a.py path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bpy.utils.user_resource('SCRIPTS', "addons")
```

use this code can get you the path your custom addon you install at.
for me, it's 'C:\Users\Naoki\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.90\scripts\addons'

found the answer over here:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/20850/how-to-automatically-get-a-add-on-folders-path-regardless-of-os