# python get location of class object

Tags: python, class

I want to create a variable within a Class object that includes the location of itself, irrespective where I call it from.

I did some search and best I got was

```
import inspect

class test():
    def __init__(self):
        self.location=inspect.getmodule(self.__class__)

s=test()
s.location
```

But it doesn't give me the actual directory of the class.

How do I get something in the form of 'C:\user\...'

Comment: `self.location = os.path.abspath(__file__)`?

Comment: Did you read this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430372/how-do-i-get-the-full-path-of-the-current-files-directory

Comment: this worked for me " Path(__file__).parent "