# Make a function that uses caller script path

Tags: python

I am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3430395/15853075) approach to get the current directory of a file:

```
import pathlib
pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.resolve()
```

Is it possible to extract this string into a function, that will use the path of the caller? My attempt:

```
# a.py
import bb.b
print(bb.b.get_current_path(__file__)) # OK: path to a.py directory (.)
print(bb.b.get_current_path()) # WRONG: path to b.py directory (bb)
```

```
# bb/b.py
import pathlib
def get_current_path(file=__file__):
    return pathlib.Path(file).parent.resolve()
```

Is it possible to avoid using `__file__` in `a.py`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) module to inspect the stack. Though it satisfies the given condition

```
# bb/b.py
import inspect
import pathlib

stack = inspect.stack()
file_importer = stack[6][1]    

def get_current_path(file=file_importer):
    return pathlib.Path(file).parent.resolve()
```

I'm not sure if import will be always at the frame with the index 6. Search through `code_context` can be used instead:

```
file_importer = next(frameinfo[1] for frameinfo in stack
                     if frameinfo[4] and frameinfo[4][0].startswith('import'))
```

But this approach breaks the possibility to run `b.py`, so that exception handling of `StopIteration` is required with desired behaviour.

---

Both approaches return the direct importer of `b.py`, e.g., having a file `c.py` and calling it from `a.py` returns the path of `c.py`

```
# c.py
import bb.b
get_current_path = bb.b.get_current_path
```

```
# a.py
import bb.c
print(bb.c.get_current_path(__file__)) # OK: path to a.py directory (.)
print(bb.c.get_current_path()) # WRONG: path to c.py directory (bb)
```

Hence, depending on further conditions desired behaviour could be reached by processing `inspect.stack()`.