# What is the correct syntax for os.system(" commande"" ") in python on windows

Tags: python, cmd, operating-system

I'm trying to execute a cmd command in my python script.

But there is some ' "" ' in the cmd `commande` and I'm using the os.system python library which breaks the ' "" ' of the Python command.

```
def open_HashMyFiles():
 os.system(".\HashMyFiles.exe /MD5 1 /SHA1 1 /SHA256 1  /CRC32 0 /SHA512 0 /SHA384 0 /SaveDirect /folder "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\WinHASH_py" /scomma "oktier.csv"")
```

What syntax should I use to make this work?

I tried :

```
os.system('
os.system([
os.system(`
os.system({
```

Comment: Correct would be __not__ using [os.system](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) being deprecated since many years and should not be used anymore in newly written Python scripts, but use instead the [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html). In this case can be used simply `subprocess.run()`. Wrong is also referencing an executable to run like `HashMyFiles.exe` with a path relative to __current directory__ because of the process starting `python.exe` to interpret the Python script defines the current working directory which can be any directory.

Comment: If the executable `HashMyFiles.exe` is in same directory as the Python script file coded by you, there can be used [pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.resolve()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3430395/3074564) to get the directory with the Python script file currently running and concatenate that path with `HashMyFiles.exe` to get the fully qualified file name of the executable to run with `subprocess.run()` with using additionally perhaps also `cwd=` and the directory path which defines the current working directory for `HashMyFiles.exe` on running it.

Comment: I recommend to read the Microsoft documentation for the Windows kernel library function [CreateProcess](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) and the [STARTUPINFO](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-startupinfow) structure. Every Python programmer writing a Python script using the `subprocess` module instead of `os.system()` for running a Windows executable should know how processes are created on Windows and what is the current directory for each started process.

Comment: By the way: `os.system()` uses also `CreateProcess` but without Python script programmer having any control over the parameters and always starting `%ComSpec%` which on Windows usually expands to `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe` with the argument `/c` and the command line defined in the string literal appended as additional arguments. If that arguments list is syntactically correct for Python and for `cmd.exe` (two script interpreters making it more difficult to use the correct syntax), `cmd.exe` uses also `CreateProcess` to run the executable. So `cmd.exe` is not needed on using `subprocess.run`

Comment: PS: I recommend to read also the Python documentation for [Built-in Types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html) (especially the section about __Text Sequence Type — str__), the chapter [String and Bytes literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals-1) and [Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the backslash escape character `\`. If you need a `"` in your string *and* you want to use `"` as the string delimiter, you'll need to "escape" your inner quotation mark.

```py
# Don't use this code, see below for a better version of this
def open_HashMyFiles():
 os.system(".\HashMyFiles.exe /MD5 1 /SHA1 1 /SHA256 1  /CRC32 0 /SHA512 0 /SHA384 0 /SaveDirect /folder \"C:\Users\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\WinHASH_py\" /scomma \"oktier.csv\"")
```

You need to be careful with this escape character in your file paths - if one of your folders starts with `n` and you put a `\` to symbolize accessing the folder, it will combine into a `\n` and become a new line! Usually for these cases we use the `r` string flag to prevent unnecessary escape sequences from working.

```py
def open_HashMyFiles():
 os.system(r".\HashMyFiles.exe /MD5 1 /SHA1 1 /SHA256 1  /CRC32 0 /SHA512 0 /SHA384 0 /SaveDirect /folder \"C:\Users\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\WinHASH_py\" /scomma \"oktier.csv\"")
```

With the `r` flag, the only escape sequences that will work are to escape the quotation characters. Useful if you use `\` in your string but don't need newlines.

But possibly the easiest way is to use single quotes if you aren't strict about what string delimiter is used. The `r` flag works on this too.

```py
def open_HashMyFiles():
 os.system(r'.\HashMyFiles.exe /MD5 1 /SHA1 1 /SHA256 1  /CRC32 0 /SHA512 0 /SHA384 0 /SaveDirect /folder "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\WinHASH_py" /scomma "oktier.csv"')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use single quotes arround and make your string a [raw-string](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) as you got unescaped backslashes in your command:

```
def open_HashMyFiles():
 os.system(r'.\HashMyFiles.exe /MD5 1 /SHA1 1 /SHA256 1  /CRC32 0 /SHA512 0 /SHA384 0 /SaveDirect /folder "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\WinHASH_py" /scomma "oktier.csv"')
```