# Python script does not create files in Docker container when run from a batch file

Tags: python, docker, batch-file

I have a Python script which needs to be run inside a Docker container (because that's how a piece of software needed is installed). This script creates some files that are needed for later processing.

When I run in the Command Prompt

```
docker exec -it CONTAINER bash
python3 script.py
```

the script does generate the files. However, I tried to use a batch file to automate the process:

```
docker exec -it CONTAINER python3 script.py
```

The script does run, since it prints information in the Command Prompt, but it does not create the files I need. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: perhaps you can share some/all of `script.py`? i'd be particularly interested in anything pertaining to file path formation. e.g. maybe your files are getting created, but not where you think?

Comment: You shouldn't usually use `docker exec` to install software, since that will be lost as soon as the container exits.  Can you `RUN ./script.py` in a Dockerfile instead?  How are you verifying that the output is or isn't present?

Comment: @ghatzhat You actually made me think twice about where it was saving files. I had assumed that the script would save where the file was (which was actually another folder). Turns out it was saving in the root instead.

Comment: If a script file like `script.py` uses just file names without path on opening files for read/write operations, it references the files in the current directory. Which directory is the current directory is defined by the process starting an executable like `python3.exe`. So it would be a good idea to improve `script.py` by [getting the file path of the script file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430372/) and referencing all files opened for read/write with that path to work independent on which directory is the current directory on processing the Python script.

Comment: @Mofi Thanks to your comment I figured a good enough workaround. Since I'd prefer the files to be in the same folder as the script, I just changed the working directory when using ```docker exec```

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to the comments from [ghatzhat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3855591/ghatzhat) and [Mofi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3074564/mofi) I figured the issue: the script was saving files in the `root` folder in the container. This was because I hadn't specified the file path in `script.py`.

Since I'd like the files to be in the same folder as the script no matter where it is, and changing the path inside the script would take some work, I instead changed the working directory in the batch file by using

```
docker exec -w FOLDER_SCRIPT CONTAINER python3 script.py
```

where `FOLDER_SCRIPT` is where the script is located.

Honestly, it seems obvious in hindsight, but guess that's part of learning curve. Thanks again to ghatzhat and Mofi for their helpful comments!