# How to run a python script relative to its location?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, exec

I have a python script on another drive:

```
E:/myscripts/run.py
```

I am running this from cmd like this:

```
python
```

Once I am in the python interpreter, I just do this:

```
file = "E:/myscripts/run.py"
exec(open(file).read())
```

It throws an error "No such file or directory: config.txt". This is a file the script opens inside:

```
open("config.txt")

os.getcwd()
```

returns C:/Users/me

So it's trying to find the config file there. How can I tell python to look for the related files relative to where the executing script is?

Do I have to specifically change the current directory? Because if I do:

```
os.chdir("E:/myscripts")
```

then run my script again, it works. But I was hoping to have some arguments to run the script properly from where it resides.

Comment: "Do I have to specifically change the current directory?" Yes you do, although you can avoid hardcoding the directory name by parsing the path name of the file: `os.chdir(os.path.dirname(file))`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Because I am trying to help people who are not very technical to run the script, so this all makes it a bit harder than just drag the script on cmd window to run.

Comment: If you are allowed to change the script itself, you should really avoid `open("config.txt")` in the first place and always open the file with its full path name.

Comment: @blhsing: Well that's even worse. Because even though I can change the script, I don't know where the user will run the script from. The script could be in any directory.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the full path of the current file's directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430372/how-do-i-get-the-full-path-of-the-current-files-directory) PS: The directory separator on Windows is ``\`` and not `/` as on Linux/Mac as explained by the Microsoft documentation about [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file).

Comment: The Python modules [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) and [os.path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) have both functions to get a directory or file path with the native directory separator of the operating system being recommended to use at least on printing an information for a user with a directory or file name with path.

Answer (score 1):

In your `run.py` script, you could first use the OS package to determine the current path of your `run.py` script and thus load `config.txt`.
To determine the full path of your currently running script you can use the following command:

```
import os
path2runpy = os.path.dirname(__file__)
```

If you print the variable path2runpy with the `print` command the following path should appear:

```
E:/myscripts/
```

Then you can concatenate the path plus the filename and load the file:

```
open(os.path.join(path2runpy, "config.txt"))
```

`os.getcwd()` will only give you the current directory, from where you are calling the script.