# How do I create a relative file path for MS Access database stored in same file

Tags: python, ms-access, pyodbc, relative-path

I'm having trouble connecting my python program to my access database relatively. My python file and database are stored in the same file however as I need to use the code on different pcs the file directory wont be the same

```
conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\Folder\Database.accdb;')
```

My python file is also stored in the 'Folder' Folder
however I'm just being told it is not a valid path

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3430395/2144390

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the full path of the current file's directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430372/how-do-i-get-the-full-path-of-the-current-files-directory)