# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory for Streamlit

Tags: excel, csv, computer-science, streamlit, file-not-found

I am trying to make a streamlit dashboard but just to get started, I am trying to import my csv file with data. I added the csv file into the file in which I am working with on vscode which is pictured. I also coppied the path of the csv file which is

```
"C:\Users\solim\AppData\Roaming\.anaconda\navigator\.anaconda\navigator\scripts\FinalProject\survey.csv"
```

this path matches up to the path of where my python code is that I run for streamlit but once again it keeps saying that the file cannot be found even though it is exactly where my python code is I just do not understand and it is very frustrating.

**Error when I run:**

[image: Error when I run]

**Proof that the file name is spelled correct and the file is in my folder:**

[image: Proof]

I am expecting the file data to be printed on my streamlit page.

Comment: Does the `survey.csv` file appear when you `import os; print(os.listdir(os.curdir))`

Comment: where should i insert the file name into  print(os.listdir(os.curdir))?

Comment: When you print the contents of the current directory, you should see the file name listed. You do not need to insert the file name anywhere. This is just a check to see what your program believes to be the current working directory, and whether your file is located in that directory.

Comment: @ScottC oh ok thank you for the response, when I printed, this is what it shows ['mental.py', 'survey.csv', 'survey.xls'], so that means the file is in the directory, why is it still not found?

Comment: @ScottC do you know the syntax for printing the absolute path with the file name to pd.read_csv() ?

Comment: This is probably what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430372/how-do-i-get-the-full-path-of-the-current-files-directory

Comment: the path of the csv file and the python file are the same so I am still confused why the file is not found, very frustrating and confusinng

Comment: I think it may have something to do with how you are running the streamlit app:
This may help: https://awesome-streamlit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/vscode.html#running-your-streamlit-app

Comment: And this may also help: https://medium.com/geekculture/how-to-run-your-streamlit-apps-in-vscode-3417da669fc

Comment: @ScottC thank you so much, the second link helped

Answer (score 0):

[screenshot of launch.json code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIEBa.png)
Enter `"args": ["run", "${file}"]` into j.son file

Follow the steps from [this tutorial](https://medium.com/geekculture/how-to-run-your-streamlit-apps-in-vscode-3417da669fc) to get to launch.json. After, the file should be found

Comment: The link might be behind paywall. Please copy relevant code to answer.