# Creating a folder and writing to a file inside that folder using python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create a new folder at the location where the python script is saved and then create a new file inside that folder and write information to it.
What would be the best way to create the folder and then the path for the file?
Thanks a lot.

I used the following code to create the folder

```
import os
from os import path

nameofFolder = "TestFolder"
foldercheck = os.path.isdir(nameofFolder)
if foldercheck:
    print('Folder present')
else:
    os.makedirs(nameofFolder)
```

I tried using

```
completepath = os.path.join(nameofFolder +"/", fileName)
```

to create a path for the file but that keeps creating the file in the root directory.

Comment: Try printing os.getcwd() inside the program. That will tell you what the current working directory is. Make sure it is what you expect.

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3430395/828193. Use `import pathlib;
pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.resolve()` to get the directory where the python file is stored at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create the folder:

```py
import os

currentPath = os.getcwd()
nameofFolder = "TestFolder"

if not os.path.exists(currentPath + '/' + nameofFolder):
    os.makedirs(nameofFolder)
```

To create a file inside of it:

```py
fileName = "Hello"

f = open(nameofFolder + "/" + fileName, "w")

# writing whatever you want:
f.write(...)

f.close()
```

Or more conveniently:

```py
with open(nameofFolder + "/" + fileName, "w") as f:
   f.write(...)
```