# "No such file or directory: './settingsicon.png'" PIL

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library, customtkinter

[A Screenshot of my folder and the script that causes trouble](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Niomo.png)
Hi guys, I want that my program opens the file with the PIL package `"settingsicon.png"` and with the usage of the path `./x` but it does not work. It says `"No such file or directory: './settingsicon.png'"`

I try it with the libary `os` but it does not work ether.

```
import os
from PIL import Image
import customtkinter

# Get absolute file path
file_path = os.path.abspath('path/to/settingsicon.png')

# Load image
img = Image.open(file_path)
```

Comment: Hey, from the screenshot, I can see that your working directory is `C:\Users\bayez` which is not the directory of your python file.
You need first to change your working directory.
And if that's vscode, I think you can just hit the "Run" button

Comment: "./" doesn't necessarily represent the folder the script is in. It represents the current working directory which can and often is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either put the full path or execute it in the directory that has the script and Image.
or make it use the script's directory in code like:

```
script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

image_path = os.path.join(script_dir, "settingsicon.png")

settingsicon = customtkinter.CTkImage(dark_image=Image.open(image_path), size=(18, 18))
```

this should work, based on the code in your screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the path of the current script from `__file__` as discussed here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3430395/21012339

That way you won't have to `cd` into the folder each time.

If / when you organize your program into a package, there's an even more pythonic way:

```
from importlib.resources import files
file = files(__package__) / "myfile.xyz"
mytext = file.read_text()
myimage = Image.open(file) #may or may not work without converting to path string
```

Comment: Is it possible without a new libary?

Comment: ```importlib``` is part of Python. The solution using ```__file__``` only imports standard libs, as well. I don't see how that would be problem.

But as others pointed out, you could also stick to the ```os``` module and achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(**file**))

image_path = os.path.join(script_dir, "settingsicon.png")

settingsicon = customtkinter.CTkImage(dark_image=Image.open(image_path), size=(18, 18))

Thank you all for your help :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Edit: Remove typo error in line 9.

Try this:

Add this `ImageTk.PhotoImage`.

Snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk
import os
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = tk.Tk()
import customtkinter

# Get absolute file path
file_path = 'p1.png'

# Load image
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(os.path.abspath(file_path)))
 
tk.Label(root, image=img).pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]