# Generated file path return FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, pandas, path

Python program generating a file path with

```
os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))
```

after creating variable

```
BAP_DATA_PATH = os.path.join(scriptdir, "BaptismTiltesTooPictures.xlsx")
```

when trying to use that as an argument in pandas read_excell

```
bap_pic_df = pd.read_excel(io=BAP_DATA_PATH)
```

returning FileNotFoundError

This is the file path generated

```
C:\\BaptismalSlideShow\\BaptismTiltesTooPictures.xlsx
```

When I remove the double backslash and paste into file explorer it does bring up the correct excel sheet

```
from pptx import Presentation
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import os
import sys
from collections import Counter
from pptx.util import Inches, Pt
from pptx.enum.shapes import MSO_SHAPE
from PIL import Image
from pptx.dml.color import RGBColor
import numpy as np

scriptdir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))
now = datetime.datetime.now()

TEST_FILE_PATH = os.path.join(scriptdir, "master.pptx")
BAP_DATA_PATH = os.path.join(scriptdir, "BaptismTiltesTooPictures.xlsx")
test_save = os.path.join(scriptdir, "Generated Baptismal Slide Show (Generated {}).pptx".format(now.strftime("%b %d, %Y at %I %M %S")))
WHEAT = os.path.join(scriptdir, "Wheat.jpg")

print ("test")
print (BAP_DATA_PATH)

bap_pic_df = pd.read_excel(io=BAP_DATA_PATH)
```

Tried manually putting in a string instead of the BAP_DATA_PATH variable, also did not work

Comment: Use `__file__` to get the path of the current script. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430372/how-do-i-get-the-full-path-of-the-current-files-directory

Comment: Where are the double backslashes coming from? None of the code you show should do that.

Comment: `scriptdir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))` Show us exactly how this program is executed, including the actual value for `sys.argv[0]`.

Comment: The actual value returns as 'C:\\BaptismalSlideShow\\CreateSlideshowV2.py'. Do you want me to add the rest of the program to the post?