# how to solve error problems in django settings.py

Tags: python, django, cmd, frameworks

When my friend used the same coding, but in coding he experienced an error in the settings.py file
with the source code error in this section BASE_DIR = Path(**file**).resolve().parent.parent

the resukts in cmd when he wants running the server
NameError: name 'file' is not defined. Did you mean: '*file*'?

I've looked for it but don't know the answer

Comment: Please read [How do I get the full path of the current file's directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3430395/3074564) That is what the *Python* script code should do but is not working because of a wrong typed variable reference.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use ***`__file__`*** instead of ***file***

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
```

the `__file__` indicate the current file in the python