# Getting folder path to script errors after compiling with pyinstaller

Tags: python, tkinter, operating-system, icons, pyinstaller

I am working on a small gui using Tkinter when I set the path to the icon in the script it works fine but when I run it as a exe file it says it cant be found and the path it displays is AppData\Local\Temp. What am I doing wrong?

`root.iconbitmap(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))+"\\Icon.ico"`)

for pyinstaller I am using this line:

```
pyinstaller "Filename" --onefile
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have ran into this problem before. Don't use `os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))` to get the path the file is currently running in, but rather use `sys.argv[0]`.
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1297407/13990977) for further explanation.