# add ico file to executable in pyinstaller

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.5, pyinstaller

I have written a small program in `tkinter` in `python 3.5`

I'm making executable out of it using `pyintaller`

I have included a custom icon to the window to replace default feather icon of tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import webbrowser

calculator = Tk()
calculator.title("TBE Calculator")
calculator.resizable(0, 0)
iconFile = 'calculator.ico'

calculator.iconbitmap(default=iconFile)
```

icon works fine when running `program.py` file directly

But when making it executable using

```
pyinstaller --onefile --windowed --icon=program.ico program.py
```

and running program.exe from dist directory, it gives error as

```
failed to execute script program
```

I also tried with

```
pyinstaller --onefile --windowed --icon=program.ico --add-data="calculator.ico;ico" program.py
```

But still same error.

**program.spec** file

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['program.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\anuj\\PycharmProjects\\YouTubePlayer\\Program'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          name='calculator',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=False , icon='program.ico')
```

Removing the line `calculator.iconbitmap(default=iconFile)` works fine but with default feather icon.

**How to include window icon file with .exe executable?**

Answer (score 1):

Try to provide absolute path for your icon file as well as bundling `.ico` file via `datas` PyInstaller argument.

`datas` should be list of tuples like `('what_to_bundle.ext', 'there_to_place_it')` (see [docs](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/spec-files.html#adding-data-files)), so add something like

```
...
binaries=[],
datas=[('calculator.ico', '.')],
hiddenimports=[],
...
```

Thus, `calculator.ico` will be placed in root dir of your app (then bundling to one file, pyinstaller creates an executable which extracts all files in temp folder and then run as usual in one-dir mode).

Next, you can find a path to icon file from your script using `sys._MEIPASS` variable set by PyInstaller (see [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42615559/5827010)). This should do the trick:

```
import os
import sys
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import webbrowser

calculator = Tk()
calculator.title("TBE Calculator")
calculator.resizable(0, 0)

if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    application_path = sys._MEIPASS
elif __file__:
    application_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)

iconFile = 'calculator.ico'

calculator.iconbitmap(default=os.path.join(application_path, iconFile))
calculator.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it is late but try using

```
pyinstaller --onefile --windowed --icon program.ico program.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add here, for me the problem was that I was writing the path with '/' to separate diretories and windows wants you to use '\\'.

exemple:
`path/to/icon.ico` -> falied
`path\\to\\icon.ico` -> succeeded

This in the `.spec` as you putted in your file.