# Pyinstaller, spec, Include different files

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller

Trying to include 3 files which are used in the script `scriptName`.

1. JSON file.
2. Driver file.
3. Logo icon

Tried to do it with `--add-data`  but this option is for non-code use files.
So I tried `spec` file.

```
##specName.py##

block_cipher = None

added_files = 
         [
         ( 'jsonfile.json', '.D:\\Directory\\jsonfile'), 
         ( 'logo1.ico', '.D:\\Directory\\logo1'),
         ( 'chromedriver.exe', '.D:\\Directory\\chromedriver')
         ]


a = Analysis(['gui.pyw'],
             pathex=['D:\\Pyton\\...\\scriptName'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=added_files,
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='MyExcutable.exe',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=False, icon='D:\\Pyton\\...\\logo1.ico' )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               name='gui')
```

finaly`--pyi-build specName.spec` then right after making one executable file

```
pyinstaller.exe --onefile --windowed --icon=logo1.ico scriptName.py
```

EDITED
By the way, on the script I'm using this function for relative path -

```
def resource_path(relative_path):
    if hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
        return os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, relative_path)
    return os.path.join(os.path.abspath("."), relative_path)
```

(It gets the orignial path)

But the exe does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: Please enable console(with `console=True` in spec file) and run your executable from a command line and put the full error log.

Answer (score 0):

1. I think I invoked `pyinstaller` directly on the spec file like so 
   `pyinstaller.exe specName.spec`. 
   spec file states the script name, whether it's onefile etc. I'd guess the last line you wrote above actually produces a new spec file.
2. As far as I remember, second element in tuples passed as `datas` parameter should hold a *relative* path (which will be interpreted / created relative to temporary folder to where the executable will "[self-extract](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operating-mode.html#how-the-one-file-program-works)". See e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/404744/determining-application-path-in-a-python-exe-generated-by-pyinstaller) on how to find these files/path afterwards. If you need to refer to an external file, you should use direct paths in your application's configuration / code. Alternatively, you can include it in the bundle and manually copy it to an external location (which seems a somewhat weird thing to do though).
3. As the pyinstaller manual states, it may be worth to first debug in "one-directory" setting, including making sure all relevant files are included, and only then pass to onefile mode (which will be relatively straightforward at this point)