# QML/PySide2 Executable - no sounds

Tags: python, qt, qml, pyinstaller, pyside2

I'm trying to create fully working onefile executable from QML+PySide2 app. I'm using auto-py-to-exe (tried also PyInstaller). Firstly created .exe did not want to start (there wasn't main.qml file), but thanks to this post: [PyInstaller and QML Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58035550/pyinstaller-and-qml-files) and @eyllanesc answer - 3rd method worked (only the 3rd). And the problem now is that app works, but without sounds (button clicks, etc.). The console displays the following messages:

```
defaultServiceProvider::requestService(): no service found for - "org.qt-project.qt.mediaplayer"
defaultServiceProvider::requestService(): no service found for - "org.qt-project.qt.mediaplayer"
defaultServiceProvider::requestService(): no service found for - "org.qt-project.qt.mediaplayer"
```

(I have 3 sounds files)

My file structure is as follows:

```
sounds
     ├── button_click.mp3
     ├── check.mp3
     └── uncheck.mp3
appIcon.png
appIcon.ico
FunkcjePython.py
main.py
main.qml
qml.qrc
qml_rc.py
```

Problem now is also that there is no sound even when I run it in Pycharm

main.py

```
import sys
import os

from FunkcjePython import Bridge
import qml_rc

from PySide2.QtGui import QGuiApplication, QIcon
from PySide2.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine
from PySide2 import QtCore


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setWindowIcon(QIcon("appIcon.png"))
    os.environ["QT_QUICK_CONTROLS_STYLE"] = "Universal"

    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    bridge = Bridge()
    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("pybridge", bridge)
    engine.load(":/main.qml")

    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

qml.qrc

```
<RCC>
  <qresource prefix="/">
    <file>main.qml</file>
    <file>sounds/button_click.mp3</file>
    <file>sounds/check.mp3</file>
    <file>sounds/uncheck.mp3</file>
  </qresource>
</RCC>
```

So what can I do to make the sounds work in the pycharm project and later in the .exe file?

Comment: what is  your    OS?

Comment: Windows 10 Pro x64