# Python os.makedir isn't working after compiled to an exe with PyInstaller?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am trying to compile Python code with this line in it, and it's not making any directories, but everything else is working.

```
os.mkdir('{}\\{}'.format(dir_path, scenario['name']))
```

I compiled with the --console flag, and there are no errors when running. I also ran as admin. Thanks for any help.

Here is how I got dir_path

```
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    dir_path = sys._MEIPASS
else:
    dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

Comment: Are you sure your path is right? Do a system search. It may have created the directory somewhere you didnt expect (such as root level). How do you derive `dir_path`, can you show that code?

Comment: It was working on source code, and I got this dir_path from another stackoverflow thread which had a similar error, except it didn't fix it for me.

```
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
        dir_path = sys._MEIPASS
    else:
        dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

Comment: Can you add that to the question so I can see the format? Paths change between local development and deployed.

Comment: I added to the question thanks for help!

Comment: What do you get when you print `os.getcwd()` and the string you pass to `os.mkdir()`?

Comment: printing os.getcwd() -> C:\Users\{username}\Documents\Source

printing  '{}\\{}'.format(dir_path, scenario['name']) -> C:\Users\{username}\Documents\Source\Scenario1

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse, You were right, I found where it's generating the files to. It's going to C:\...\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI158442\Scenario1, But I want it to generate in the directory where the .exe is in.

Comment: @wazoo3 haha, I've experienced similar issues before. Do you create an installer or just an executable?

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse Just an executable.

Comment: Take a look at [Determining application path in a Python EXE generated by pyInstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/q/404744/8150685). I think you are close but just need to change something minor.

Comment: @wazoo3 make sure you read the third comment for the second answer in that link. (That is your issue).

Comment: If you end up solving the issue though, add it as an answer, it may help future users.

Comment: Awesome, thanks, I am returning the correct path now. However now I am getting permission error when trying to write the csv to the newly created dir. I've tried using mode=0o777, no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202673/discussion-between-error-syntactical-remorse-and-wazoo3).