# Why use getattr instead of hasattr for sys.frozen?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, executable, cx-freeze, sys

Every documentation and answer I could find, says that in order to check if the program is "frozen" (an exe for example), we can use `getattr(sys, 'frozen', False)` in the following way:

```
import sys
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    print('program is frozen exe')
else:
    print('program is a .py script')
```

Where `False` is returned by default if the `frozen` attribute doesn't exist instead of throwing an AttributeError. An example from the console:

```
>>> getattr(sys, 'frozen')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'sys' has no attribute 'frozen'
>>> getattr(sys, 'frozen', False)
False
>>> hasattr(sys, 'frozen')
False
```

This is all fine, but there is a shorter version of this that does the same job, unless I'm missing something:

```
hasattr(sys, 'frozen')
```

Which simply returns `True` or `False` without the need to specify a default. Despite this being shorter and possibly more readable, every documentation and answer online uses `getattr` instead. I'm sure there's a clever difference I might be overlooking, which is why I'm asking this question.

Example sources that refer to `getattr`:

- [Determining application path in a Python EXE generated by pyInstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/404744/determining-application-path-in-a-python-exe-generated-by-pyinstaller)
- [Pyinstaller documentation](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/runtime-information.html) (Even uses `hasattr` on something else)
- [Cx_Freeze documentation](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html)

Comment: `hasattr` only tells you if the attribute exists, it won't return its value in case it does.

Comment: Adding to @ThierryLathuille's answer, and thus by using `getattr` you'll get the value of `frozen` attribute and if it is `True` then only the `if` part is executed. If you wanna do it with hasattr, do `if hasattr(sys,'frozen') and sys['frozen']:`.

Comment: What if the attribute exists and its value is `False`…?

Comment: I see your point. Are there any examples of when it's useful to force `sys.frozen` to exist and be `False`? Or any packages / extensions / program that do it?

Comment: Thanks to your question I found that there was a missing `True` in the `PyInstaller` manual which led to an error when run: https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/runtime-information.html

Answer (score 2):

The PyInstaller documentation itself uses the `getattr` style block of code [here](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/runtime-information.html), so by the copy-paste effect, it will proliferate.

So then the question becomes: why does the PyInstaller documentation do it this way? As others said in comments, `sys.frozen` could theoretically be set to `False` or some other [falsy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) value, in which case, `hasattr(sys, 'frozen')` would still return `True`:

```py
>>> class Stuff:
...     pass
... 
>>> x = Stuff()
>>> x.yes = True
>>> hasattr(x, 'yes')
True
>>> getattr(x, 'yes', False)
True
>>> x.no = False
>>> hasattr(x, 'no')
True
>>> getattr(x, 'no', False)
False
```

But as used by PyInstaller, is it possible for `sys.frozen` to be set, but with a falsy value? Let's check the source code:

```py
$ git clone git://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller
Cloning into 'pyinstaller'...
...
$ cd pyinstaller
$ git grep '\(sys\.frozen\|frozen = \)' PyInstaller
PyInstaller/loader/pyiboot01_bootstrap.py:    sys.frozen = True
PyInstaller/utils/win32/winutils.py:            # True if "sys.frozen" is currently set.
PyInstaller/utils/win32/winutils.py:            is_sys_frozen = hasattr(sys, 'frozen')
PyInstaller/utils/win32/winutils.py:            # Current value of "sys.frozen" if any.
PyInstaller/utils/win32/winutils.py:            sys_frozen = getattr(sys, 'frozen', None)
PyInstaller/utils/win32/winutils.py:            sys.frozen = '|_|GLYH@CK'
PyInstaller/utils/win32/winutils.py:            # If "sys.frozen" was previously set, restore its prior value.
PyInstaller/utils/win32/winutils.py:                sys.frozen = sys_frozen
PyInstaller/utils/win32/winutils.py:                del sys.frozen
```

So this variable is only set in two scenarios:

1. To `True`, while loading/bootstrapping; and
2. To `'|_|GLYH@CK'` temporarily in a utility method.

It never receives a falsy value from PyInstaller.

So in practice, using `hasattr(sys, 'frozen')` will work fine. It just feels wrong from a correctness perspective, because it's an incorrectly handled edge case, which is probably why the PyInstaller documentation uses `getattr` instead: it's more [future-proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Future-proof).