# python: the usage of __file__

Tags: python, spyder

When I run

```
print(__file__)
```

in Spyder, the absolute location is returned (e.g. C:\Users\test\test.py).

However, when I run the same code after I compiled it into an exe via pyinstaller, only the name of the py file is printed (just test.py).

How can I fix this?

Comment: Pyinstaller runs in a different context, so what do you expect to see?

Answer (score 1):

In an exe `__file__` is not accurate, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48817163/1672644) previous answer.

In short:

```py
import sys
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    # Pyinstaller exe
    location = sys.executable
else:
    # Running directly python
    location = __file__
```