# os.path.basename(__file__) gets script name, not file

Tags: python

I'm making an evaluator for a type of extension called '.way'.
To open the file, you have to go to the files properties, select 'Open with Way.exe' and then open the file. 
This is Way.exe's code:

```
import os
currentname = os.path.basename(__file__)
print(currentname)
```

When I run test.way, it prints 'Way.py' (The script that the .exe file runs) instead of 'test.way'. How do I get it to print the current file's name?

Comment: The predefinded `__file__` variable is defined to be the name of the current script file.

Comment: So how can you get the current file name? Thanks for replying.

Comment: Sorry, it's unclear to me what file you want to get the name of — please [edit] your question and try to be more clear about that.

Comment: Why would Python know to print `'test.way'`? How can it possibly know that's what to print? See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Have a looks at [**`sys.argv`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv). It contains the script name and any other parameters passed to the python interpreter on the command line.

Comment: *"test.way" is the module and the script* is hard to understand. The way most of us use those terms, the running file is a program or a script, and when it is running or imported, it is a module.

Comment: @PeterWood Thank you! Your answer solved my problem. If you could post it as an answer, I would love to check your post.

Comment: I don't really want to answer the question as it needs improving drastically. It should be closed really. It won't help anyone else find the solution in future, as it's not a good statement of the problem which `sys.argv` solves.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
from pathlib import Path
print(Path(__file__).resolve())
```

more details can be found in https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html

Answer (score 0):

I think I faced the same problem and this fixed it. Hopefully this helps

The following code snippet was referred from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/404744/determining-application-path-in-a-python-exe-generated-by-pyinstaller)

```
import os
import sys

# determine if application is a script file or frozen exe        
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    file_path = os.path.realpath(sys.executable)
elif __file__:
    file_path = os.path.realpath(__file__)
    
currentname = os.path.basename(file_path)
```