# Python-Pyinstaller -- can not get the file path properly when ran from a different directory after being converted to .exe

Tags: python, path, pyinstaller, executable

I am trying to print the directory of the .py file however I want to run the file from another directory by adding the file's directory to the system Path file. I ran in to some problems when I turned to file to an executable with pyinstaller.

The code in the file:

```
import pathlib

path= pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.resolve()

print(path)
```

Let's say the directory of the file is: C:\Users\User\Documents\file.py

And let's say the current working directory is: C:\Users\User

**When I run file.py I get:
C:\Users\User\Documents**
which is the output I want

**When I run file.exe I get:
C:\Users\User**
which is not what I wan't

I don't understand why the .py and .exe files are working differently.
What can I do to fix the problem?
I tried a bunch of stuff from here but none of them seem to work:
[How do I get the full path of the current file's directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430372/how-do-i-get-the-full-path-of-the-current-files-directory)

Comment: Tested this on linux, but it seems to work there, so I can't test this locally now. What is `__file__` in either case?

Comment: file.py:
C:\Users\User\Documents\file.py---
file.exe:
file.py
Sorry for the delayed reply

Comment: I found a solution on:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/404744/determining-application-path-in-a-python-exe-generated-by-pyinstaller/404750#404750